# Seperation of path in csv file

Tags: pandas, csv

I am facing a problem regarding separation of path of files in a csv file.
I have such a structure in a csv file:

```
w:b/c/v/n/1/y/i

w:b/c/v/n/2/h/l

w:b/c/v/n/3/n/r

w:b/c/v/n/4/f/e
```

this is one column of my csv file as the path name. Now what I need to do is to preserve my first column and create 3 more columns for:

```
1/ y /i
2  h  l
3  n  r
4  f  e
```

I know that `.str.split('/', expand=True)` works in such a cases but my problem is how to show that it should leave out "b/c/v/n" part. Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have DataFrame like this:

```
              path
0  w:b/c/v/n/1/y/i
1  w:b/c/v/n/2/h/l
2  w:b/c/v/n/3/n/r
3  w:b/c/v/n/4/f/e
```

Then:

```py
df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]] = (
    df["path"].str.split("/", expand=True).iloc[:, -3:]
)
print(df)
```

creates 3 new columns:

```
              path col1 col2 col3
0  w:b/c/v/n/1/y/i    1    y    i
1  w:b/c/v/n/2/h/l    2    h    l
2  w:b/c/v/n/3/n/r    3    n    r
3  w:b/c/v/n/4/f/e    4    f    e
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first get a slice of the string and then use split like the following:

`.str[10:].str.split('/', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Another try is:

```
s = 'w:b/c/v/n/1/y/i'
temp = s.split("/")
s = "/".join(temp[0:4]) + "," + ",".join(temp[4:7])
```

Result is:
`w:b/c/v/n,1,y,i`

Answer (score 0):

concise solution

```
df[['col', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df['path'].str.rsplit('/',3, expand=True)
df
```

```
    path               col        col1  col2    col3
0   w:b/c/v/n/1/y/i     w:b/c/v/n   1     y      i
1   w:b/c/v/n/2/h/l     w:b/c/v/n   2     h      l
2   w:b/c/v/n/3/n/r     w:b/c/v/n   3     n      r
3   w:b/c/v/n/4/f/e     w:b/c/v/n   4     f      e
```